# How to add external library (ODE) to OpenFrameworks QTCreator application (C++)

Tags: c++, makefile, qt-creator, ode, openframeworks

I'm trying to make a small graphical simulation using Open dynamics engine and Open Frameworks for my University course and I'm having trouble adding an external library to my make/config.make file and my lecturer couldn't figure it out so here it goes. Apologies but I'm pretty newbie to C++.

I'm including ode as a header and syntax highlighting works after that so all seems fine with the library. However on compile I get:

```
 error: undefined reference to 'dInitODE2'
```

and the same error for any other component of the library. I've tried adding the library to the config.make files with:

```
PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATHS = /home/noah/ode-0.16.2/ode/src/.libs
PROJECT_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=home/noah/ode-0.16.2/ode/src/.lib
PROJECT_CFLAGS = "-I /home/noah/ode-0.16.2/include"
```

However I still get the same error when trying to run in QTcreator.

I've tried different directories and just general messing around with stuff but I'm out of my depth as this is the first time I've worked with make files so any help is appreciated. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something simple.

I don't know if it's helpful but I can compile the project manually in the terminal with:

```
g++ -o bin/test  obj/linux64/Release/src/main.o obj/linux64/Release/src/ofApp.o   /home/noah/of/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/libopenFrameworks.a   -Wl,-rpath=./libs:./bin/libs -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--gc-sections -fuse-ld=gold -L/home/noah/of/libs/fmod/lib/linux64/ -lfmod /home/noah/of/libs/kiss/lib/linux64/libkiss.a /home/noah/of/libs/tess2/lib/linux64/libtess2.a   -lz -lgstapp-1.0 -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -ludev -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lsndfile -lopenal -lcurl -lglfw -lrtaudio -lpulse-simple -lpulse -lasound -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lmpg123 -lglut -lX11 -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXi -lXcursor -ldl -lpthread -lfreeimage -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lpugixml -luriparser -lXinerama `-L ~/ode-0.16.2/ode/src/.libs -lode`
```

When running 'make' in the terminal I just took the G++ command and added on the library for ODE manually

```
-L ~/ode-0.16.2/ode/src/.libs -lode
```

Update with more info. Making any kind of changes seems to have no affect. Any suggestions on how the QBS file of.include & cxx flags would be great.

The make file looks this:

```
# Attempt to load a config.make file.
# If none is found, project defaults in config.project.make will be used.
ifneq ($(wildcard config.make),)
    include config.make
endif

# make sure the the OF_ROOT location is defined
ifndef OF_ROOT
        OF_ROOT=$(realpath /home/noah/of)
endif

# call the project makefile!
include $(OF_ROOT)/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/makefileCommon/compile.project.mk
```

There is also a QBS project file with reference to flags and linkers but I can't find documentation on how to use these.

```
files: [
            'src/main.cpp',
            'src/ofApp.cpp',
            'src/ofApp.h',
        ]

        of.addons: [

        ]

        // additional flags for the project. the of module sets some
        // flags by default to add the core libraries, search paths...
        // this flags can be augmented through the following properties:
        of.pkgConfigs: []       // list of additional system pkgs to include
        of.includePaths: []     // include search paths
        of.cFlags: []           // flags passed to the c compiler
        of.cxxFlags: []         // flags passed to the c++ compiler
        of.linkerFlags: []      // flags passed to the linker
        of.defines: []          // defines are passed as -D to the compiler
        // and can be checked with #ifdef or #if in the code
        of.frameworks: []       // osx only, additional frameworks to link with the project
        of.staticLibraries: []  // static libraries
        of.dynamicLibraries: [] // dynamic libraries

        // create a console window when the application start
        consoleApplication: false

        // other flags can be set through the cpp module: http://doc.qt.io/qbs/cpp-module.html
        // eg: this will enable ccache when compiling
        //
        // cpp.compilerWrapper: 'ccache'

        Depends{
            name: "cpp"

        }

        // common rules that parse the include search paths, core libraries...
        Depends{
            name: "of"
        }

        // dependency with the OF library
        Depends{
            name: "openFrameworks"
        }
    }
```

The config.make file that the make file calls upon looks like this and is mostly commented out:

```
################################################################################
# CONFIGURE PROJECT MAKEFILE (optional)
#   This file is where we make project specific configurations.
################################################################################

################################################################################
# OF ROOT
#   The location of your root openFrameworks installation
#       (default) OF_ROOT = ../../.. 
################################################################################
# OF_ROOT = ../../..

################################################################################
# PROJECT ROOT
#   The location of the project - a starting place for searching for files
#       (default) PROJECT_ROOT = . (this directory)
#    
################################################################################
# PROJECT_ROOT = .

################################################################################
# PROJECT SPECIFIC CHECKS
#   This is a project defined section to create internal makefile flags to 
#   conditionally enable or disable the addition of various features within 
#   this makefile.  For instance, if you want to make changes based on whether
#   GTK is installed, one might test that here and create a variable to check. 
################################################################################
# None

################################################################################
# PROJECT EXTERNAL SOURCE PATHS
#   These are fully qualified paths that are not within the PROJECT_ROOT folder.
#   Like source folders in the PROJECT_ROOT, these paths are subject to 
#   exlclusion via the PROJECT_EXLCUSIONS list.
#
#     (default) PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATHS = (blank) 
#
#   Note: Leave a leading space when adding list items with the += operator
################################################################################
PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATHS = "-L/home/noah/ode-0.16.2/ode/src/.libs"

################################################################################
# PROJECT EXCLUSIONS
#   These makefiles assume that all folders in your current project directory 
#   and any listed in the PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCH_PATHS are are valid locations
#   to look for source code. The any folders or files that match any of the 
#   items in the PROJECT_EXCLUSIONS list below will be ignored.
#
#   Each item in the PROJECT_EXCLUSIONS list will be treated as a complete 
#   string unless teh user adds a wildcard (%) operator to match subdirectories.
#   GNU make only allows one wildcard for matching.  The second wildcard (%) is
#   treated literally.
#
#      (default) PROJECT_EXCLUSIONS = (blank)
#
#       Will automatically exclude the following:
#
#           $(PROJECT_ROOT)/bin%
#           $(PROJECT_ROOT)/obj%
#           $(PROJECT_ROOT)/%.xcodeproj
#
#   Note: Leave a leading space when adding list items with the += operator
################################################################################
# PROJECT_EXCLUSIONS =

################################################################################
# PROJECT LINKER FLAGS
#   These flags will be sent to the linker when compiling the executable.
#
#       (default) PROJECT_LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=./libs
#
#   Note: Leave a leading space when adding list items with the += operator
#
# Currently, shared libraries that are needed are copied to the 
# $(PROJECT_ROOT)/bin/libs directory.  The following LDFLAGS tell the linker to
# add a runtime path to search for those shared libraries, since they aren't 
# incorporated directly into the final executable application binary.
################################################################################
# PROJECT_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=./libs

################################################################################
# PROJECT DEFINES
#   Create a space-delimited list of DEFINES. The list will be converted into 
#   CFLAGS with the "-D" flag later in the makefile.
#
#       (default) PROJECT_DEFINES = (blank)
#
#   Note: Leave a leading space when adding list items with the += operator
################################################################################
# PROJECT_DEFINES = 

################################################################################
# PROJECT CFLAGS
#   This is a list of fully qualified CFLAGS required when compiling for this 
#   project.  These CFLAGS will be used IN ADDITION TO the PLATFORM_CFLAGS 
#   defined in your platform specific core configuration files. These flags are
#   presented to the compiler BEFORE the PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS below. 
#
#       (default) PROJECT_CFLAGS = (blank)
#
#   Note: Before adding PROJECT_CFLAGS, note that the PLATFORM_CFLAGS defined in 
#   your platform specific configuration file will be applied by default and 
#   further flags here may not be needed.
#
#   Note: Leave a leading space when adding list items with the += operator
################################################################################
PROJECT_CFLAGS = "-I /home/noah/ode-0.16.2/include"

################################################################################
# PROJECT OPTIMIZATION CFLAGS
#   These are lists of CFLAGS that are target-specific.  While any flags could 
#   be conditionally added, they are usually limited to optimization flags. 
#   These flags are added BEFORE the PROJECT_CFLAGS.
#
#   PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_RELEASE flags are only applied to RELEASE targets.
#
#       (default) PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_RELEASE = (blank)
#
#   PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_DEBUG flags are only applied to DEBUG targets.
#
#       (default) PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_DEBUG = (blank)
#
#   Note: Before adding PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS, please note that the 
#   PLATFORM_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS defined in your platform specific configuration 
#   file will be applied by default and further optimization flags here may not 
#   be needed.
#
#   Note: Leave a leading space when adding list items with the += operator
################################################################################
# PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_RELEASE = 
# PROJECT_OPTIMIZATION_CFLAGS_DEBUG = 

################################################################################
# PROJECT COMPILERS
#   Custom compilers can be set for CC and CXX
#       (default) PROJECT_CXX = (blank)
#       (default) PROJECT_CC = (blank)
#   Note: Leave a leading space when adding list items with the += operator
################################################################################
# PROJECT_CXX = 
# PROJECT_CC =
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add the `-L` and `-l` flags to PROJECT_LDFLAGS?

Comment: @JimRhodes I have tried it like that, and with and without inverted commas. Should it definitely be with -L? That it least stops me trying it without them again

Comment: Are you sure that your changes to `config.make` are doing anything? I don't see any of them in the `g++` command line.

Comment: I just tried a random bunch of symbols in the config.make with no error so I doubt. I'm gonna post an update now with more info how the config files are laid out. @JimRhodes